# Sharepoint 2013: How to get all Lists a user has access to from Provider Hosted app using CSOM

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I'm trying to get a list of all `Lists` that a user has access to in a given SharePoint 2013 site. Specifically right now I'm testing against a SharePoint Online site and authenticating via AccessTokens.

I have it working against a specific site in the SharePoint instance `https://myinstance.sharepoint.com/sites/development-testing` (where I am an administrator) if my App is granted the `<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list" Right="Read"/>` permission and using the following code:

```
ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(  sharepointUrl.AbsoluteUri, accessToken )
clientContext.Load( clientContext.Web.Lists );  
clientContext.Load( clientContext.Web.CurrentUser, user1 => user1.LoginName );
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
var listsICanAccess = new System.Collections.Generic.List<List>();
foreach ( var list in clientContext.Web.Lists )
{
    if ( ( list.BaseTemplate == (int) ListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary )
                             || ( list.BaseTemplate == (int) ListTemplateType.MySiteDocumentLibrary ) )
    {
        listsICanAccess.Add( list );
    }
}
```

However I am unable to make the same call against the top level site `https://myinstance.sharepoint.com` (where I am not an administrator). My hunch is that I am able to query the first site because my user is an admin but I'm not sure. Am I making the right call to get that information?

Comment: what access do you have on the https://myinstance.sharepoint.com site ? Do you have a read access ?

Comment: I have read access to the myinstance.sharepoint.com site. Via the browser I can navigate to it, open different teamsites and contribute to them.

Comment: what error do you get when the call is executed for that site ?

Comment: The error I receive is `Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource` which is confusing because I definitely have read access to the site.

Comment: If it helps, I'm authenticating and authorizing with `TokenHelper` using the `TokenHelper.GetAppContextTokenRequestUrl` method.

Comment: what if you hard code the URL of the site while getting the token ? Just for testing purpose !

Comment: I think my user does not have access to the top level site. If I dive down into the teamsites `https://myinstance.sharepoint.com/teams/teamsite` I can get access. I'm going to follow up with the admin to figure out what's going on with my permissions. Thanks for the help.